# ReactNative app crashes FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Tags: crash

I am making a request to the api with axios and after getting the results, the app crashes. I mention that the request returns only json text.

The request finishes successfully, promise returns success, only thing is that the app crashes without debug logs, only the provided logcat log.

```
    Process: host.exp.exponent, PID: 23720
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 25090000 byte allocation with 6291456 free bytes and 18MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 390069440, growth limit 402653184
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:410)
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:894)
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:708)
        at android.util.JsonReader.objectValue(JsonReader.java:691)
        at android.util.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:347)
        at abi31_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.onMessage(JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.java:187)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.i.a.b(RealWebSocket.java:307)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.i.c.e(WebSocketReader.java:222)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.i.c.a(WebSocketReader.java:101)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.i.a.b(RealWebSocket.java:262)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.i.a$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:201)
        at expolib_v1.a.y$a.c(RealCall.java:135)
        at expolib_v1.a.a.b.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I expected it to work... instead, I get this error message.